# D3.js how prevent drag-start on click event

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, click, drag

I am using [D3.js](https://d3js.org) v4 library. I need to discriminate between click and drag-start event: if it is a click event, I don't want the drag-start to be fired. It seems it is possible the other way around (prevent click if dragstart is fired). Any idea if this is doable?

```js
var svg = d3.select("#svgContainer").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);
  
var onDrag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", function() {
    $("#console").append('<p>drag-start</p>');  
    console.log("drag-start");
  })
  .on("drag", function() {
  
  })
  .on("end", function() {
  
  });
  
var box = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 25)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .on("click", function() {
    $("#console").append('<p>click</p>');
    console.log("click");
  })
  .call(onDrag);
  
  
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#console").empty();
});
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 8px;
  font-size: 8px;
}

#svgContainer {
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:  #333;
}

#console {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 150px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.2/d3.js"></script>


<div id="svgContainer"></div>
<div id="console"></div>
<button id="btn">Clear</button>
```

Comment: A click is a `mousedown + mouseup`. However, the drag start is fired at `mousedown`. How can the code tell what `mousedown` is happening?

Comment: I feared the drag was triggered at mousedown. I always thought that any drag event was associated with some kind of delta in the mouse (or touch) position but it seems the design has been chosen differently

Comment: That's the drag event. I'm talking about "drag start". There are three drag events: start, drag and end. Have a look at the table here: https://github.com/d3/d3-drag The drag itself is triggered at `mousemove`.

Comment: Exactly. For now I have solved moving the drag-start logic on the drag event and using a flag to check if that's the first drag event occurrence

Comment: Moving the drag-start logic to the drag event and using a flag to check if that's the first drag is a good option.  I also had the same problem and I did the same way - and it works !!

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing here, but I would probably do something like:

```
var dragger = null;
var onDrag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", function() {
        dragger = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#console").append('<p>drag-start</p>');  
            console.log("drag-start");
        }, 100);
    });
var box = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 25)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("fill", "orange")
    .on("click", function() {
         $("#console").append('<p>click</p>');
         console.log("click");
         clearTimeout(dragger);
     })
    .call(onDrag);
```

So, your drag start will be delayed by 100ms (or whatever you want), and if the click happens before that delay, it cancels the timeout.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this gives unpredictable results (depends on when the mouseup occurs)